# Meaning and translation of: 钱米?

Tags: meaning

I have this sentence here:

[image: picture]

> 乱花钱米叫“泡稍”

Another reference also confirms this saying:

> ②形容(手头) 宽裕 ▷他的钱～，尽是大手大脚的用。

References for `钱米`, though, are very few.

古汉语大词典's entry for **俸恤** says:

> 旧时官史除俸禄外，其亲属所受之钱米，称俸恤

ABC defines it as:

> payment and pension

Grand Ricci says

> traitement et allocations

Could we just combine the English and the French to define 钱米 as `payment and allocations` or, more simply, `money and food`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *more simply, money and food?*

Basically, yes. It is a common practice in Chinese or English to use a couple of representative items to form a general term for a single concept.

'**钱米**' (coins and rice) can be used as a general term for '**wealth / resources**'

> '旧时官史除俸禄外，其亲属所受之 **钱米**，称俸恤'

- **钱米** (coins and rice) refers to consumables resources like money and food
- **俸恤** (allocations) is a portion of resource assigned to particular recipient.

'**钱米**' (coins and rice) can also be used as a general term for  '**wealth / consumables resources**', as in '乱花 **钱米** 叫“泡稍”'

Similarly, '鱼米' (fish and rice) is a general term for 'natural food resources' in the phrase '鱼米之乡'(land of plenty) ; '刀剑'(knife and sword) refers to all 'weapons' in '刀剑没眼'(weapons have no eyes)

- In old time war campaigns, 钱粮 (coins and grain) is a common term for 'resources' like soldiers' salary, food and horse feed.

> "*打仗就是打钱粮* "